What would be the ideal blade for puncturing pressure armor?
Blades, sometimes, pose an advantage to firearms. In my case that advantage is relative silence. Additionally, there's far less risk of depressurization if you're inside a pressurized vessel—a great way to make sure the guy whose space suit just got nailed with your sword can't make it out without converting him and everyone else into a fine pink mist. Assuming pressure gear (i.e., space suits) in this universe is somewhat more advanced than what we have here on Earth, made of carbon-fiber plating and Kevlar or similar materials and relatively non-bulky (a little like the recent Space-X designs in shape and thickness), how could one design a blade that could puncture the seal between the astronaut and the great black void—would serration be optimal, and what material would provide the greatest chance of tearing through?

A quick point: If your in a vacuum or even a very thing atmosphere i.e the type of environment where a full pressure suit is required for survival as opposed to just a separate oxygen supply mountain climbers or firemen for example might need? You don;t really need to worry about silence because in space? No one can hear you fire than gun shot! This is because there's no medium (gas) for sound waves to propagate through except any physical surfaces you may be in contact with.

(a) Your title says "pressure armor," your body text says "space suits" but discusses kevlar, which was invented not to be a body armor, but to strengthen automobile tires - it was designed to be puncture resistant. So, are we dealing with armor or not? (b) This is a practical dichotomy. Which is best is irrelevant, that's a storybuilding choice based on how you want to rationalize the weakness. You're problem is rationalizing a weakness that isn't better taken advantage of with a bullet (a short, high-speed knife).

If you're imagining guys exploding like ruptured balloons upon puncturing their pressure suits... don't. There's about a 25kpa difference in pressure between the inside of the pressure suit and vacuum, about 1/10 the difference in pressure between the inside and outside of a bottle of soda at room temperature. If two astronauts get in a knife fight, they both asphyxiate 30 minutes later.

Would you like to injure or kill the the guy right now, or just make sure their suit gets damaged?

Silence is important? Lasers are silent, and a little AI could make sure it only fires when aimed at a bad-guy space suit, and not a bulkhead.

The same things that are best at puncturing anything, I fail to see some reason in your question why the trivial answer is not the best answer, suggesting you haven't tried to think about it yourself before asking at even the most basic level?

Are you worrying about things being too loud in the vacuum of space? And firearms can be modified with vibration isolation to prevent solid-mediated sound transfer.

@Mon: Based on the ‘fine pink mist’ detail the pressure difference here is much more than that between a vacuum and one atmosphere. I wonder if this might be about a sub-surface vessel of some sort, or a decompression chamber. But walls that can withstand pressures like that aren't likely to be bothered by a knife blade.

"Relative silence" isn't really an advantage in space. Think about it....

@tofro - you might not be able to hear a gunshot with your naked ear, but the combustion gasses will fly out in every direction and make themselves known at any sensor in the area.  I would expect a reasonably advanced spaceship to identify the chemical makeup of the gas and the heat implied by the velocity of the particles, to reconstruct their trajectories back to the source (even if they bounced a few times en route) and correctly identify the precise location of the gunshot - before the sound, if audible, would have been processed by the human ear.

@MikeSerfas The gases from the punctured space suit will do the same....

@tofro - true, but they'll go a bit slower because they're cold.  More importantly, they'll be gasses plausibly released by ordinary mishaps like disconnecting a tank with a valve stuck open; they don't scream "bullet" the moment they strike the analyzer.  They don't add up to a life-threatening emergency until after some seconds or minutes have passed.  And, of course, you don't detect them if the attack missed.

A War Hammer or Bec de Corbin.

Image from https://www.antiqueweaponstore.com/product/saxon-warhammer-2nd-half-16th-c/

Image from https://www.facebook.com/historicalweaponology/posts/bec-de-corbin-hungary-ca-1530-bec_de_corbin-lucerne_hammer%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE/1517749445190715/
These weapons were invented in the medieval era to do the same job as the OP desires, only against steel plate armour, not modern composites.
A war hammer is a one-handed weapon similar in appearance to a common pick, with a flat-headed hammer-like head on one side, and a pointed, slightly curved, long head like that of a gardening pick on the other side.
Unlike a gardening pick, a war hammer designed to puncture pressure armour would be made from hardened steel, and the pick-head might have a cross-section rather more like an X than a square, so that the edges of the X could be sharpened so that it would be more likely to cut through fibrous polymers and composites.
War hammers have been shown to have impact forces of several hundred kilograms per square millimetre, similar to that of a rifle bullet.
The edges of a space-age war hammer would be unlikely to be visibly serrated, since large serrations would make the weapon more likely to hang up in an enemy's suit.  I would expect that the initial X cross-section would gradually change to an oval O cross-section as the pick head approached its maximum width, so that it could be loosened from its embedment in the enemy's armour by twisting the handle so that the pick head rotated along its long axis, pushing aside the material of the enemy's armour.
So, I would expect that a modernised war pick would be just as effective against space-age armour as it was against historical armour.

Reading your answer, I just remembered a key factor. I suppose OP is asking for melee weapon to deal with space-suits... while fighting in space. So the fighters are likely not moving very fast, and swinging around is going to be very awkward. On one hand, having a weapon with some heft and a decent lever to push it into the target will definitely help. On the other... I am now picturing people moving like goofy cartoony hippo-ballerinas, swinging bec-de-corbins at each other in space.

@Nyakouai in space, dual-wielding would actually be very useful (as opposed to mostly cinematic in gravity) - counter the rotation you get from one warhammer swinging at the enemy with the one in your other hand! (Of course the rotation you get from hitting the enemy is different, but at least you won't rotate until you do hit something^^)

Don't forget the ubiquitous mag-boots...

@Nyakouai That is a wholly hilarious image. That said, could some sort of propulsion or stabilization system be devised to streamline said hippo-ballerina warfare?

@Asterion That's your story and your world. If you tell me your space-suits have precise propulsion control made specifically to allow for space bouts, it's cool. As Monty Wild mention, you could also have mag-boots, or whatever thingamabob you deem able to fix this - if you think it's an issue! I suppose if that is a common occurence, people will figure out the aspects of fighting in vacuum/zero-g. It would possibly influence fighting styles, for example. Fun topic.

This would also be good for non combat uses during an infiltration.  It's got a hook, so you can push or pull yourself to maneuver is zero-g.  It's a pry bar for opening or destroying things.  It's a good tool

@Asterion You could ask another question about it... but in theory, you could have miniature thrusters and/or reaction wheels to compensate for rotation.

@Asterion Another option for not having the wielder rotating due to swinging the pick is to make it a rocket pick like Ido Daisuke's from Battle Angel Alita

Why not go the extra step and make it an axe, especially a battle axe with 2 points and a blade a la the first image on Wikipedia's Battle Axe page.

@Asterion Something to counter Newton's Third Law would be absolutely necessary. Otherwise, every time someone swung their weapon, they would spin in the opposite direction, especially if the weapon collided with something. Either an anchoring mechanism (e.g. magboots) or a light power suit designed to compensate against the swinging motion would do. Otherwise, there would need to be some form of zero-g martial arts that built up the momentum necessary to deliver killing blows, and that has several issues in itself (not least of which that every attack would be extremely telegraphed).

East of the Sun, West of the Moon by John Ringo used this exact solution.

Kind of hard to use in enclosed spaces though.

You would probably want something more like a long stiletto dagger
(and one that was piston or magnetically driven at that.)
Basically it would be an attachment to one (or both) arms of your pace suit with the blades recessed inside a housing. When going into hand to hand combat the operator activates the device/s which include an impact operated trigger. Whenever a strike at your opponent hits? The trigger activates and the blade is 'punched' out of its module at extremely high speed - hopefully penetrating your foes armor. The suit then automatically retracts and resets the blade/s for another strike unless the command to do so is overridden by the user. Alternately the operator can switch off the 'impact' trigger (for example by using a simple HUD icon) and set it so that the blades  can be deployed when grappling an opponent as opposed to just when striking with the option of ordering them to retract and/or strike on command.
This would be way less bulky than a sword or axe and much more easy to use in confined spaces like inside a breached space ship or station.

Reminds me of flechettes! Very cool.

@Asterion If I may, the general consensus is that  your supposed to select the answer to your post that best suits your imagined purpose. In this case? The war hammer answer was voted the most popular. It might well be what you chose, it's up to you. That aside. It's just generally neater if you close of the question by selecting the answer  you most approve of (unless none of them) satisfy you.r original criteria.  And no. I don't want you to select mine (I've already scored points) :)

Perfect! Sure-can-do.

Modernized plate armor in zero gravity could counter normal melee weapons
The thing is, metallurgy and armor technology have gotten a lot better since medieval times. Plus the combatants are weightless in space, which makes it possible to wear thicker armor than medieval knights did.
Getting through a medieval knight's plate armor was already a very challenging proposition. Double or triple the thickness, eliminate the joint weak points with modern design and manufacturing, and make it out of flawless titanium? Forget about it!
In contrast, muscle-powered melee weapons have not improved much. They can be made out of better materials so they won't break, but it's not like a medieval warhammer was going to break anyway. And then there's the fact that it's much harder to generate force behind a strike when you're in zero-gravity.
So the conclusion is that you simply cannot get through a seriously designed set of zero-gravity plate armor with any melee weapon. Not a sword, hammer, or bec-de-corbin; you can't get through a 3mm plate of modern steel or titanium. Your strike will bounce off and barely leave a dent.
What will work against such armor?

Bullets. Bullets will go through any wearable thickness of plate armor. Sure, bullets can also accidentally destroy important life support and propulsion systems, but if your side was likely to lose and get killed anyway, you'll be willing to risk using guns. That means the other side also has to risk using guns or they'd be the ones losing.
Bullets again, but at point-blank range. Does this count as a melee weapon? It would be safer in terms of not destroying essential systems, because the bullet would get stopped by the enemy's body. You could even have an automatic rangefinder that refuses to shoot unless the muzzle is in physical contact with the enemy. Of course, again, the side that chooses not to equip the rangefinder would be at a huge advantage.
Thermal lance.
A nonlethal option: Sticky foam. It's not likely to destroy the life support systems!


Probably a relatively thin and fine blade
Doing some reading around Carbon Fibre and Kevlar, it does appear that special coatings are needed to consistently cut it (diamond coated blades).
That said, both these materials derive their strength from the multiple strands and fibres in the weave, so anything that is fine enough to pass through the gaps and cut a few strands as it penetrates is going to be ideal.
I would imagine something like a Rapier or the Fencing Foil type sword, where the method of attack is not to slash at the enemy, but to thrust with the point, passing the blade between a few fibres, cutting them and weakening the structure.

The special coatings aren't necessarily required to cut kevlar or carbon fabrics - they're used to improve the durability of the cutting tools because the materials are very abrasive and will make your scissors or knife blunt quickly.
likewise if you are sawing or grinding through a hard composite with kevlar or carbon weave, you want a very hard grinding compound or saw so that it lasts a useful amount of time.
neither should be a huge concern for a weapon you probably are only going to stab with a few times.

Any sharp needle point dagger
You want a fine point and a sharp edge but othrwise they will go right through kevlar. You don't want serations they will hang up. A hard steel is important as well.
the real issue is the carbon fiber and resin, you really really want to aim between the plates of that, since its not flexible the entire thing can't be made of it. But as long as it is not too thick a blade can still get through it, but you need a lot more force so something like a dagger where you can get a lot of leverage is important. Something like a rondel dagger which is designed to be weilded by bulky gauntlets or gloves will work well.


A mechanical pike
My proposal is a mechanical pike: A pointy knife on top of an extendible telescope arm.
If this does not meet your definition of a blade, then you could make the top a bit longer and give it sharp sides, so it becomes more a halberd than a pike.
Heavy swinging weapons may be difficult to handle in zero gravity and also in closed environments (e.g. inside of a space station), but you probably still want something that can provide a bit of range.
The mechanical pike/halberd is a compromise between a gun and a blade:

the range is limited (you won't accidentially shoot the window at the other end of a room) but still provides some range to hit
the mechanical telescope arm may provide enough extra force to make a hole in an armor
it can be small enough to carry when not needed
in really close combat it may be used as a short sword or dagger
the recoil is a straight line instead of a rotation
you won't run out of ammunition
it is more or less silent (which should not matter without an atmosphere)


A fast vibrating diamond string thrown out and recollected by a device to keep a blade shape. The vibration is produced via piezzo electricity. If it breaks, both ends are retracted, a new filament is thrown out. It has no extra weight, it adapts the cutting surface to the surface to cut, its basically the perfect chainsaw minus the weight of the blade.

Bangsticks
Modern armor is way too hard to break or bypass with a traditional melee weapon, especially in zero G where you can not brace your attacks. Modern, machine made chainmail similar to a shark bite suit can be designed to be flexible enough to protect every joint on your body, tough enough to stop any stabbing or cutting weapon, and fine enough to prevent even narrow blades from getting between the gaps.
Furthermore, we now have polycarbonates and synthetic sapphire which allow us to make armor grade clear face masks.  In short, you can not just get in close with a dagger to get around the armor like you could against a medieval knight or expect to pierce the armor with something low powered like bow or crossbow.
We've also gotten much better at making impact resistant armor.  A football helmet is rated to protect against a 2500 Newton impact, most melee weapons only strike with a few hundred newtons of force. Granted, you'd have to replace the plastic shell with a tougher metal shell to keep it from being penetrated, but the only way to get a percussive kill against modern padding might be to use a pole hammer/axe/pick, but in zero g, such weapons would be way to unwieldy to swing, and in the narrow spaces of a ship or space station, you'd not have enough room to swing them properly anyway.
In short, historical melee weapons are a bad choice and modern firearms are too dangerous, but luckily, there is a middle ground called bangsticks.  Bangsticks use a gunpowder charge to drive a piston several inches into a victim with all of the force of a point blank shot from a gun, but then it uses a spring or hydraulics to catch and return the piston so that there is no bullet flying off.  This way you get all of the killing power of a firearm, with none of the risk of collateral damage.
Since I'm assuming most of your fighting will be done in narrow confines similar to the inside of a naval ship, you will want your weapon to resemble a short spear.  Long enough to perform a basic phalanx with, but not so long that you can not maneuver them through doorways and turns or around enemy shields.  To make it a military grade weapon, will also want to give them multiple shots and a contact firing mechanism.
This way, you only need to tap an enemy's armor (hopefully while grasping a dead man's safety trigger) to deliver a fatal blow.


Everyone else is wrong!
Ok, that's a bold statement, there are a lot of great points (lol) in the other answers.  BUT:  A spacesuit that's likely to be worn in combat with people with pointy sticks,  will very likely have some sort of self-healing properties (e.g. gunk floating around inside that will find and self-seal and small holes.)  A sharp-pointed war hammer, or a stiletto blade etc. will make a small, narrow opening that will be sealed up as soon as the blade is removed.
I think you need to look at vehicular spike strips for inspiration.  The point of the blade could be a hollow 'needle' like design, such that a big hole gets punched in the armour, and , importantly, some of the armour material is removed, leaving a large hole, rather than just a tear or a puncture.
You could maybe look at a detachable needle-design,  like the stinger of a bee,  that leaves a needle inserted into the armour,  holding open a hole for the air to escape.  This could be coated in hydrophobic material that stops and 'gunk' sticking to it, making it even less likely to be blocked.  https://magnumspike.co.uk/ has a good example.

I think sealing the hole of your suit has two major problems. First is that 'self healing' suits can be difficult with this application. Let us draw the comparison with tires. You can seal it easily, if the hole isn't too large. Some answers aren't tiny nails. They can puncture and make hefty holes that are difficult to seal. To have this all over the suit is a health or logistical nightmare. The second is that regardless of puncturing the armour, you're puncturing the occupant. A 20cm spike into your body is not a good time, regardless if it hits something vital.
